# javascript function to calculate perimeter and area using heron formula

Tags: javascript, function

I have to do an assignment to calculate the perimeter and the area of a triangle using heron`s formula.
My code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Perimeter of the triangle </title>

</head>

<body>
<h1>The perimeter is:</h1>


<script>

let latura1, latura2, latura3, p, s;

function perimetru(latura1, latura2, latura3){
latura1 = parseInt(prompt("Introduceti prima latura"));
latura2 = parseInt(prompt("Introduceti a doua latura"));
latura3 = parseInt(prompt("Introduceti a treia latura"));

if(latura1 + latura2 <= latura3 ||
latura1 + latura3 <= latura2 ||
latura2 + latura3 <=latura1)
return "Suma a doua laturi trebuie sa fie mai mare decat latura a treia";
else
return p=latura1+latura2+latura3;


}

document.write(perimetru());



</script>
<h1>Triangle Area</h1>
<script>

function arieHeron(latura1, latura2, latura3){

s=p/2;
return Math.sqrt(s*(s-latura1)*(s-latura2)*(s-latura3));

}
document.write(arieHeron());

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

After running in the browser I get a NaN for the area...
Can anybody explain me why?
Thanks.

Comment: i took the variables latura1, latura2, latura3 outside the function and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you do prompt you got back a string... Also a numerical string like "3",  instead of 3 as a number..

So to fix it you have to add "+" before the prompt:

```
someVar = parseInt(+prompt("enter something"))
```